# Is there a way to remove a class from a div after the action has happened?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making an image changer (you could call it like that), the point is that an image changes after a certain time. I have coded the system already, my problem is that I'm adding a fade-in animation through a class, so what I want is for the image to fade in when it appears. Just look at my code:

The HTML:

```
    <figure id="changing-image"></figure>
```

The CSS:

```
.fade-in{
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}


#changing-image{
      background-image: url(../images/asides/Interior.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      width:  60rem;
      height: 50rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 2px;
  }
```

The JavaScript:

```
 const imagesArray = ["url(img1)", "url(img2)", "url(img3)", "url(img4)"];
const changeImage = i => {
    if (i < imagesArray.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('changing-image').style.backgroundImage = imagesArray[i];
            document.getElementById('changing-image').classList.add("fade-in")
            changeImage(++i);
        }, 2600);
    } else if (i === imagesArray.length) {
        changeImage(0);
    }
    document.getElementById('changing-image').classList.remove("fade-in")
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `classList.remove` immediately before the `classList.add`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: you have a strange way of using the figure tag, it prevents me from answering you! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Comment: @BrettDonald  read the PO title : **after the action has happened**

Comment: Add the fade-in class in the element itself. Just change the image url. it should work. OR maybe insert an img tag and change it's url with fade-in fixed.

Comment: @MisterJojo the code contains a loop, so all you need to do is remove the class right before you need to add it back in.

Comment: @BrettDonald actuly his code made a flash  and then a fade in animation... and the point of his question is how to detect the end of his animation and not re solve his bad code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lookimg for the [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)
but you missed the issue of initial load time of each new image which may exceed your `setInterval()` timeout

I've chosen here to just use a promise.all to take care of this

```js
const
  imageArray = 
    [ { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300', status:'none', img:null }
    ]
, loadImage = ref => new Promise( resolve =>
    {
    ref.img = new Image();
    ref.img.onload  =_=>{ ref.status='OK';  resolve() };
    ref.img.onerror =_=>{ ref.status='bad'; resolve() };
    ref.img.src = ref.path;
    })
, changingImage = document.querySelector('#changing-image')
  ;
// *******************************************************
// animationend event 
changingImage.onanimationend =_=>
  {
  changingImage.classList.replace('fade-in','opa1')
  }
// *******************************************************


// main code...
Promise
.all(imageArray.map(el=>loadImage(el) )) // load all imgs
.then(()=>
  {
  for(let i=imageArray.length;i--;)    // remove 
    {                                  // unloaded images
    if (imageArray[i].status==='bad') 
      imageArray.splice(i, 1)
    }
  if (imageArray.length===0)
    {
    console.log('problemo! no image are loaded!')
    return
    }

  let currentImg = 0
  setImage(currentImg)

  setInterval(()=>
    {
    currentImg = ++currentImg % imageArray.length
    setImage(currentImg)
    }
    , 5000)
  })

function setImage(indx)
  {
  changingImage.className = 'opa0' 
  changingImage.src = imageArray[indx].path 
  changingImage.classList.replace('opa0','fade-in')
  }
```

```css
.opa0 { opacity: 0; }
.opa1 { opacity: 1; }

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
  }
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
  }

#changing-image {
  display : block;
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 300px;
  padding : 5px;
  border  : 1px solid lightseagreen;
  margin  : 1em;
  }
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="changing-image" class="opa0">
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the question of the implementation of adding a `fade-out` before the arrival of the next image in `fade-in`.

Changing the image just by modifying the `src` attribute makes the previous image appear a second time in "flash", because browsers use their cache

So I opted for a second strategy with an `appendChild()`  method

```js
const
  gApp = 
    { imgIndx : 0
    , cImg    : null
    , intvRef : null
    }
, imageArray = 
    [ { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/200', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/200', status:'none', img:null }
    , { path:'https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/200', status:'none', img:null }
    ]
, loadImage = ref => new Promise( resolve =>
    {
    ref.img = new Image();
    ref.img.onload  =_=>{ ref.status='OK';  resolve() };
    ref.img.onerror =_=>{ ref.status='bad'; resolve() };
    ref.img.src = ref.path;
    })
, changingImage = document.querySelector('#changing-image')
  ;
  

/* -------------------  animationend event ------------------ */

changingImage.onanimationend =_=>
  {
  gApp.cImg.classList.replace('fade-in','opacityOne')

  if (gApp.cImg.classList.replace('fade-out','opacityZero'))
    {
    changingImage.innerHTML = ''
    gApp.imgIndx            = ++gApp.imgIndx % imageArray.length
    gApp.cImg               = imageArray[ gApp.imgIndx ].img
    changingImage.appendChild( gApp.cImg )
    gApp.cImg.classList.replace('opacityZero','fade-in')
    }
  }

/* -------------------  animationend event ------------------ */


// main code...
Promise
.all(imageArray.map(el=>loadImage(el) )) // load all imgs
.then(()=>
  {
  for(let i=imageArray.length;i--;)    // remove 
    {                                  // unloaded images
    if (imageArray[i].status==='bad')
      imageArray.splice(i, 1)
    else
      imageArray[i].img.className  = 'opacityZero'
    }
  if (imageArray.length===0)
    {
    console.log('problemo! no image are loaded!')
    return
    }

  gApp.cImg               = imageArray[ gApp.imgIndx ].img
  changingImage.innerHTML = ''

  changingImage.appendChild( gApp.cImg )
  gApp.cImg.classList.replace('opacityZero','fade-in')

  gApp.intvRef = setInterval(()=>
    { gApp.cImg.classList.replace('opacityOne', 'fade-out') }
    , 4000) 
  })

StartStopAnim.onclick=_=>
  {
  if (StartStopAnim.classList.toggle('stopped'))
    {
    clearInterval( gApp.intvRef )
    }
  else
    {
    gApp.cImg.className = 'opacityZero'
    gApp.cImg.classList.replace('opacityZero','fade-in')

    gApp.intvRef = setInterval(()=>
      { gApp.cImg.classList.replace('opacityOne', 'fade-out') }
      , 4000) 
    }
  }
```

```css
.opacityZero { opacity: 0; }
.opacityOne  { opacity: 1; }

.fade-in  { animation: fadeIn  2s; }
.fade-out { animation: fadeOut 1s; }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
  }
#changing-image {
  display : block;
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 200px;
  padding : 5px;
  border  : 1px solid lightseagreen;
  margin  : 1em;
  }
#StartStopAnim::after         { content : 'Stop animation' }
#StartStopAnim.stopped::after { content : '...Restart animation' }
```

```html
<figure id="changing-image"></figure>
<button id="StartStopAnim"></button>
```